# How to draw a clock with JavaFX 2?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Given an hour and a minute, I want to draw an analogous clock.

I was able to create a `Group` with a `Circle`, but I don't know which class to use for the hands and how to place and rotate them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Add 3 [lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) (for hour, minute, second) with different [strokes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStroke%28javafx.scene.paint.Paint%29) and lengths to your Group.
2. Place one end of each line in the center of your circle and the other end of each line pointing straight up at 12 o'clock.
3. Create a [timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) which triggers a keyframe each second.
4. In the keyframe:

   - Calculate the degree of rotation for the hands based on the current [time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).
   - [Rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) the hands the required amount.
5. Set the timeline to [cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setCycleCount%28int%29) [indefinitely](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE).
6. Place your Group in a Scene and add the Scene to a Stage.
7. [Play](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play%28%29) your timeline.

I created a [sample app](https://gist.github.com/2658491) implementing the above principles.

[image]

*Update*

In response to [criticism](http://blog.crisp.se/2012/08/09/perlundholm/an-analog-clock-in-javafx) of the coding style used in the sample app, I created a [refactored sample app](https://gist.github.com/3388637#comments) which uses a more functional coding style.

Additionally the [jfxtras project](http://jfxtras.org/) has an AnalogueClock control.  Here is the gist of how to use the [jfxtras](https://gist.github.com/2928302) clock.

Comment: any idea how do you add pointy arrow heads to the `Line` instances ?

Comment: bvdb, please ask new questions as new questions

Answer (score 5):

Netbeans 7.1.2 is bundled with sample applications. In JavaFX part there is a **StopWatch** sample application. Have a look at it, it can give you a great clue.

Comment: yep, and also it's included into Ensemble sample which you can download from javafx.com