# How to get scene coordinates of a stationary mouse cursor in JavaFX 2.2?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

When handling any `MouseEvent` it is easy to get the mouse coordinates by invoking methods such as `event.getSceneX()` (or `event.getScreenX()` if that is what we want). Hovewer, I have no idea how to get this information outside the mouse event handling procedure, if there are no mouse events currently?

In my case: after pressing a certain hotkey, I want something to happen relative to the current mouse position. But I am unable to acquire the position information. How should I do it?

Comment: This question is similar to [How to get location of mouse in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635514/how-to-get-location-of-mouse-in-javafx)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I found at least one solution, utilising `java.awt.MouseInfo`, here is the outline of the concept:

```
if (view.isHover()) {
    Point pointerLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

    int sceneX = pointerLocation.x;
    sceneX -= view.getScene().getWindow().getX();
    sceneX -= view.getScene().getX();

    int sceneY = pointerLocation.y;
    sceneY -= view.getScene().getWindow().getY();
    sceneY -= view.getScene().getY();

    return new Point(sceneX, sceneY);
} else {
    // mouse not in view
}
```