# Clock Animation JavaFx

Tags: animation, javafx, clock

Could anyone give me an idea or a hint how can I do such clock animation in JavaFX? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Kind Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a clock with JavaFX2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541738/how-to-draw-a-clock-with-javafx-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this repository:

[Medusa](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa)